# MATLAB 2019a spawning hundreds of processes

Tags: matlab

My MATLAB 2019a on Windows 8.1, 64bit, is spawning hundreds of processes (as seen in Task Manager). These spawn even if I am not running anything in MATLAB. They all have about 10MB of RAM, but after some hours this adds up and crashes the computer.

A fresh install of MATLAB rectifies the problem, for about 3 days. How do I go about diagnosing this?

Comment: I don't think R2019a and Windows 8.1 are compatible. Check here: https://au.mathworks.com/support/requirements/previous-releases.html. I think only R2018a and earlier versions of Matlab are compatible with 8.1.

Comment: That's interesting. I've been using it since release with no issues until now.

Comment: This is something for the MathWorks technical support. If you have paid for your licence you can contact them directly. If you have an illegal copy... you're on your own.

Comment: Have you done any modifications to MATLAB files in the installation folder (e.g. startup.m file)?